# What is meant by hridaya or heart?

Tags: atma, body, prabhupada

Prabhupada in his Gita commentaries mentions the phrase "cave of the heart", where he says dwells the atomic soul.

Even Ramana Maharshi said, that the godly atom of the Self is to be found in the right chamber of the heart, about one finger-width’s distance from the body’s midline. He says- “Here lies the Heart, the dynamic Spiritual Heart. It is called hridaya, is located on the right side of the chest, and is clearly visible to the inner eye of an adept on the Spiritual Path. Through meditation you can learn to find the Self in the cave of the heart."

My question is what exactly is this hridaya or heart. Maharshi only mentioned the location of it. But what exactly is it? 
A clear definition of it would be most helpful.

Comment: Related OR Possibly Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27850/5620

Comment: Hridaya in Yoga shastra = means center. What is the center? Space between eyebrows. Once the knot opens, you get to knw it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Brahman in unmanifested state reduce to the size of half a thumb?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9300/how-can-brahman-in-unmanifested-state-reduce-to-the-size-of-half-a-thumb)

Comment: Oh and i have edited my question. It's not duplicate anymore of that other topic. Now i simply wish to know what is hridaya or heart. And not about the size of Brahman. So no need to close this discussion. Thnx.

Comment: @Akshay, But according to Maharshi, it is the centre of the chest. And not eyebrows.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse - That is also another way of looking at it. Sivananda Paramahmsar who lived in Kerala wrote about this. Hridaya = center = space between eyebrows. The key area by which one transcends body and realizes the "self"

Comment: You mean it is the area where one of the chakras lie, and when the kundalini shakti rises to this area (centre of chest/eyebrows) and activates the chakra there, one gets to have self realization?

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse - Yes, the Sushumna Nadi has to open, and the Kundalini will have to rise to that area. And to go beyond self realiziation, Turiya 10th gate has to open in head.

Comment: Closely related [Which schools prior to the Gautam Buddha gave the finite size of the atma (आत्मा )?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27117/5212). It has references to the size of the soul and he is called Angushta Purusha from Katha Upanishad.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, I have replied to you, under your answer, in this topic-  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9300/how-can-brahman-in-unmanifested-state-reduce-to-the-size-of-half-a-thumb... Could you please check it out and reply to my query there. Thnx.

Answer (score 4):

I have also wondered exactly which place is regarded as the region of heart. Because, after we have sipped during Achamana we are required to touch the seven holes of the head as well as the seat of soul (as per Manu Smriti).

Now, the seat of the soul is said to be the region of heart in the Upnishads. So, is that region is on the left of our chest where the organ of heart resides or at the middle chest or somewhere else? We need to know this because we need to touch that spot.

We can get the precise location of this region from a minor Upanishad called MahAnArAyana Upanishad (MNU).

> adho nishtyA vitastya ante (1) |
>  nAbhyAm upari tishthati (2)
>   ||
>  hridayam tat vijAniya (3) |
>  vishvashya Ayatanam mahat (4)
>   ||
>
> **That which is known as heart (3) is located above the navel (2), at
>   the distance of a finger-span (nishti) below the Adam's apple** (vitasya
>   ante). This is the great abode ( Ayatanam) of the universe.
>
> **MNU 13.7**

We precisely know where the Adam's apple is located in our throat so thus the region of heart is somewhere around the top portion of the middle of the chest.

The previous verse talks about a lotus that resides in that region (of heart) which one needs to meditate upon and this verse is precisely giving the location of the region.

The translation of 13.6 is as follows:

> On the One who is limitless, unchanging, the supreme poet dwelling in
>   the sea (of one's heart) and the cause of the happiness of the works,
>   (one who should meditate). (The place for meditation is) the ether
>   (AkAsham) in the heart which is symbolised (pratikA) by an inverted
>   lotus bud (padma kosha).

Comment: But Atman the universal spirit, pervades everything. When atman pervades or illumines the entire subtle body its called jivatma or soul. So how is it possible for the whole subtle body or soul, to be placed in the heart region, when in fact the heart region is part of the subtle body aka soul.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse you have some logical questions but Atman is beyond this logic ;)

Comment: Well the Upanishads say both the things that Brahman is everything and is everywhere and that Brahman resides in the bodies in that region of heart.. Now, how both of these claims can be simultaneously true is I guess not part of ur present Q. @TheCrimsonUniverse That is a separate Q.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse Also I thought that u are basically asking " Where according to scriptures the region of heart is situated in the body?" I was also bothered by this question previously.

Comment: @Rickross, Separate? Not really. It's definitely related to this question. Unless one knows how the whole vehicle works, the knowledge of only the engine is never going to do justice. Besides, your answer above only speaks of the location of hridaya. If you check my original post, you'll notice that i didn't ask for it's specific location. I asked for it's definition. Your answer says it's located below Adam's apple, and looks like a lotus which the sages meditate upon. You didn't explain what it actually is ... Is it a chakra? If so, why sages meditate on this one & not the topmost sahasrara?

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse Well AFAIK there is no such definition found anywhere.. This place is often referred to in the principle Upanishads but none precisely describe it's location. It's only this MNU that gives the precise location of the region of heart. Also, if it's a spot where one needs to fix his gaze or mind upon then knowing it's location is the only important thing to know about it. Sometimes the description will also be needed. Here that is provided by 13.6. It might be related to the Anahata Chakra but nothing definite to share.

Comment: Hmm no probs bro. While browsing this site, i came across a post by stack exchange user SwamiVishwananda, in which he wrote something like, hridaya is the buddhi, upon which the universal Atman shines or reflects. I wish i could request him, to provide the scriptural verse that says such a thing. If only there was a way to contact him :(

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse Yes I have also read something like that in commentaries of Upanishads. And those are coming from Advaitin scholars.

Answer (score 2):

The cave of the heart is mentioned in many Upanishads.

> Realising through self-contemplation that primal God, difficult to be
>   seen, deeply hidden, set in **the cave (of the heart)**, dwelling in
>   the deep, the wise man leaves behind both joy and sorrow.

Katha Upanishad I.2.12

The cave of the heart is also known as the heart lotus or hrit padma. Unlike the well known lotuses in the susumna channel along the spine, this lotus is in the chest.

> Next above the navel lotus (Nabhi-padma) is the Anahata, in the region
>   of the heart, which is red like a Bandhuka flower, and is so called
>   because it is in this place that Munis or Sages hear that "Sound
>   (Anahata-sabda) which comes without the striking of any two things
>   together", or the "sound'  of the Sabda-brahman, which is here the
>   Pulse of life. For it is here that the Purusa (Jivatma) dwells. **This
>   lotus is to be distinguished from the Heart Lotus of eight petals,
>   which is represented below it, where in mental worship the Patron
>   Deity (Ista-devata) is meditated upon.**

The Serpent Power *the secrets of tantric and shaktic yoga*, The Centres of Lotuses (Cakra, Padma) by Sir John Woodroffe

Comment: In Udhava Gita Krishna says to draw life air from below to center of chest where you could hear sound of Pranava.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay, Sorry i had to delete my yesterday's reply to your post, since i thought it needed some editing. Anyway, my question is, you said above that jivatma dwells in the anahata heart region. But as far as i know it, the whole subtle body plus the universal Atman's rays, is called jivatman ... (i.e jivatma = subtlebody) ... The heart region anahata u spoke of, should be IMO, part of the subtle body aka jivatma ... How could the jivatma dwell in the chest region, when the whole subtle body, including the chest region, IS jivatma. Please help me understand this.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse, what you are stating is the theory. In practice the Guru will tell you to imagine your Atma (jivatma is the same as the Paramatma according to Advaita) seated in the heart lotus and meditate. Yogis have found out through pracice that meditation works best when one concentrates on the heart lotus.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay, It still doesn't make sense. 1) Atma first of all, is all pervasive and present everywhere. Why would it dwell only in the chest region. It should be present all through out the subtle body .... And yes i know that atma and jivatma are same. The latter is simply a combination of ((atma's reflection + the reflecting medium subtle body)).

Comment: 2) Secondly, since subtle body is the reflecting medium, upon which atma's reflection falls, the subtle body is considered jivatma. This is not my theory. This is claimed by the advaitins. So if the whole subtle body is to be considered jivatma, then how can the yogis say, that jivatma dwells in the chest region of sookshma, when in fact the whole sookshma is jivatma as per advaita. I think there's a difference in opinion between the advaita sect and yoga school.

Comment: If you reread my earlier comment then you will see that you are asked by the Guru to imagine the atma in the heart lotus. This localization of the atma is necessary for concentration. In fact there are Upanishadic verses that say that atma of thumb size is in the heart lotus. This is again for concentration purpose. The Atma is not really of thumb size and is not really located only in the heart lotus. There is a channel going from the heart lotus to the higher chakras in the Susumna channel. The power of meditation on the atma in the heart drives the heated prana shakti to the higher chakras.

Answer (score 1):

In ullladu narpadu anubhandam of Ramana Maharshi,

Verses 18 to 24 are about the subject of the ‘heart’, a term that in a spiritual context means the innermost core or essence of our being. Ramana Maharshi had translated some of these verses from the Malayalam version of Ashtanga Hridayam and the rest from Yoga Vasistha.

Verses 18 and 19 describe it as being like a lily bud located within our chest, ‘two digits to the right’, and say that in the tiny hole inside its closed mouth the darkness (of self-ignorance) exists along with desire and other passions; that all the major nadis (subtle channels through which consciousness and prana flow) depend upon it; and that it is the abode of the light (of consciousness), the mind and the prana (life-force).

A more detailed description is given in the [Ramana Gita](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/ramaNagItA.itx) in the fifth chapter as recorded by Kavyakantha Ganapathi Muni.

> hrdayavidyä
>
> prAgukte.abde.aShTame mAsi navame divase nishi | upanyasitavAn
> saMyaguddishya hR^idayaM muniH || 1||
> nirgachChanti yataH sarvA
> vR^ittayoH dehadhAriNAm | hR^idayaM tatsamAkhyAtaM
> bhAvanA.a.akR^itivarNanam || 2||
>
> ahaMvR^ittiH samastAnAM vR^ittInAM
> mUlamuchyate | nirgachChanti yato.ahandhIrhR^idayaM tatsamAsataH ||
> 3||
>
> hR^idayasya yadi sthAnaM bhavechchakramanAhatam | mUlAdhAraM
> samArabhya yogasyopakramaH kutaH || 4||
>
> anyadeva tato
> raktapiNDAdadR^idayamuchyate ayaM hR^iditi vR^ittyA tadAtmano
> rUpamIritam || 5||
>
> tasya dakShiNato dhAma hR^itpIThe naiva vAmataH |
> tasmAtpravahati jyotiH sahasrAraM suShumNayA || 6||
>
> sarvaM dehaM
> sahasrArAttadA lokAnubhUtayaH | tAH prapashyan vibhedena saMsArI
> manujo bhavet || 7||

In the aforesaid Year, on the night of the ninth of August [1917], Ramana Muni spoke exhaustively regarding the Heart. 5.1

> ÒThat from which all thoughts of embodied beings issue forth is called
> the Heart. All descriptions of it are only mental concepts. 5.2.
>
> The ÔIÕ-thought is said to be the root of all thoughts. In brief, that
> from which the I-thought springs forth is the Heart. 5.3.
>
> This Heart is different from the blood-circulating organ. ÔHridayamÕ
> stands for hrit Ôthe centre which sucks in everythingÕ, and ayam
> ÔthisÕ and it thus stands for the Self.
>
> The location of this Heart is on the right side of the chest, not at
> all on the left. The light (of awareness) flows from the Heart through
> sushumna to sahasrara 5.6
>
> From there, it flows to the entire body, and then all experiences of
> the world arise. Viewing them as different from the Light, one gets
> caught up in samsara 5.7.
>
> The whole universe is in the body and the whole body is in the Heart.
> Hence all the universe is contained in the Heart. 5.11.
>
> The notion that the seer is different from the seen is only in the mind. For those that abide in the Heart the seer and the seen are one. 5.19